# Email notifications for unread messages on Mesibo

Tags: mesibo

I am trying to decide on using Mesibo for my Ecommerce website and mobile application and couldn't find any documentation on email notifications for unread messages on Mesibo. I found documentation on push notifications for the app but couldn't find anything on email notifications for unread messages on the website.

Can anyone tell me if this is something that is not included in the Mesibo API and needs to be manually coded or is there any documentation available for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the mesibo webhook to deliver offline messages only and forward them to your user email. It is explained here https://mesibo.com/documentation/faq/messaging/#is-it-possible-to-deliver-messages-via-email

Hope it helps